# Filling a Jasper Report but getting nulls

Tags: jasper-reports

Unless I read the documentation wrong, I need to use JasperFillManager.fillReport to populate a jasper report. The field variables are noted as:
$F{myVarName}

For instance. I have for this example 3 `<textField>` nodes in my jrxml
each text field contains a `<textFieldExpression>` node like this:

```
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{param1}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

I've built a service that can generate pdf as base64  that I can inject where I need it.
Here is an excerpt

```
PdfTemplate template = templateRepo.findByTemplateId(templateId)
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(new ByteArrayInputStream(template.getTemplateXml().getBytes()))
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters)
//JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource) //Also tried this.
```

Parameters looks as follows:

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();

parameters.put("param1", "Value of param1");
parameters.put("param2", "Value of param2");
parameters.put("param3", "Value of param3");
//Where param1-3 correspond with $F{param1-3}
```

When the report is generated, I only see nulls.

ie:

Parameter 1: null

Parameter 2: null

Parameter 3: null

Any help to get those parameter values to pull to the report will be appreciated.

**Reference Notes:**

https://javadoc.io/static/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/4.0.0/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperFillManager.html

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jasper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Jasper Reports, `$F{}` is for a field, not for a parameter. Change your expression to `$P{}`

Also, make sure the parameter is defined in the JRXML.

So you `textFieldExpression` should be as below.

```xml
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{param1}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Comment: Thanks. Will play with $P.

These are legacy reports that we are reusing in a new system, so they came out with $F for the fields.

Comment: Converting to $P and defining all the parameters at the top worked a charm.
It looks like Jasper insists on getting the fields via JRResultSetDataSource that you create from a ResultSet. Much easier converting it to parameters. Thanks again.

Comment: @BenFourie There are a lot of data sources you can use other than `JRResultSetDataSource.` Please take a look at https://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/.